# Disable form but keep each of its elements look like enabled

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to `disable` the whole `Form` but still, keep each of this `Form` elements like TextBox, Buttons etc to look like `enabled`.

So, I want to block user interactions on those elements, but preserve it's standard look, not grayed out etc.

Can that be done in kind of automatic way or one just need to manually handle `EnabledChanged` events for each of affected controls?

Comment: you could overlay the form with an transparent image

Comment: you can set element as "readOnly" mode.

Comment: @Komal only textboxes

Comment: @Komal read-only for button will not prevent user from clicking it.

Comment: keep elements background color to their default (Control) or any other color you want.

Comment: Set the control color explicitly to get the desired appearance. You might also need to set the border colors accordingly.

Comment: Add a transparent image on top of your form

Answer (score 1):

For all the controls, the "backcolor" property is set to window by default. Select all of them and set to white (or the desired color) to get the same appearance.
You might want to do the same with text and border color. Its all about the level of customization you want.

To have complete control over the colors, you will need to redraw them.

```
protected override void OnPaint ( System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e )
{
    if ( Enabled )
    {
        //use normal realization
        base.OnPaint (e);
        return;
    }
    //custom drawing
    using ( Brush aBrush = new SolidBrush( "YourCustomDisableColor" ) )
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString( Text, Font, aBrush, ClientRectangle );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, by the Form designer, I manually set button's `ForegroundColor` to `White` and `BackgroundColor` to `SteelBlue` and when Form is disabled, it still grays out the `ForegroundColor` of the button. The same for `DataGridView` headers.

Comment: ok. Yes, in that case you might need to redraw the text with the desired color. Which you need to analyze if that would be acceptable based on the performance and complexity. I am adding the code for the same in the answer.

Comment: @ Thanks for answer, sadly it still requires overriding paint methods for each controls in that form.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to have a transparent image on top of all controls and you just show it when you want to disable the controls.

This image will catch all mouse inputs but it is possible that the controls can still be selected by keyboard.

Comment: This image should be placed in a `pictureBox` for example? And when form gets `disabled`, I should show this `pictureBox` on top?

Comment: exactly. i will catch all mouse inputs. but it could be that you are still able to select the controls in the background with the keyboard.